# Using Microsoft Data Migration Tool on the command line

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, migration, sql-server-2019

I am using the Microsoft documentation  from the link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-commandline?view=sql-server-ver15

The sample I am using from the documentation is this one

**Target Readiness assessment for all databases on a server using Windows authentication**

My final command looks like this:

***DmaCmd.exe /Action=AssessTargetReadiness /AssessmentName="MYTESTSERVER" /SourceConnections="Server=MYTESTSERVER;Integrated Security=true" /AssessmentOverwriteResult /AssessmentTargetPlatform="SqlServerWindows2019" /AssessmentResultJson="E:\temp\results\MYTESTSERVER.json"***

I want the data migration assessment results for going to SQL Server 2019 so I added this option to My command **/AssessmentTargetPlatform="SqlServerWindows2019"**

Based on the documentation this should be easy and straight forward.
Apparently not. By running the above command I get the error error below stating invalid target platform. I copied and pasted the value from this error it does not work. I tried it without the quotes I still get the same error. Can someone tell me what is wrong with my command. My objective is to assess all the databases on the given the 2016 server for 2019 Assessment.

```
 Message:
        Invalid target platform specified for assessment. Please choose one of 'SqlServer2012', 'SqlServer2014', 'SqlServer2016', 'SqlServerWindows2017', 'SqlServerLinux2017', 'SqlServerWindows2019', 'SqlServerLinux2019', 'AzureSqlDatabase' or 'ManagedSqlServer'.
    HResult : 0x85FD0003
        FacilityCode : 1533 (5fd)
        ErrorCode : 3 (0003)
    Data:
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Fundamentals.OperationsInfrastructure.Contracts.ErrorFailureCategory = SettingValidationFailure
'
DmaCmd.exe Information: 0 : 'Exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Fundamentals.OperationsInfrastructure.Workflow.Contracts.ActionExecutionException
    Message:
        An exception occurred while running the action 'ValidateCommandLineSettings'.
    HResult : 0x84C40001
        FacilityCode : 1220 (4c4)
        ErrorCode : 1 (0001)
    Data:
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Fundamentals.OperationsInfrastructure.Contracts.ErrorFailureCategory = UnexpectedFailure
        ActionName = ValidateCommandLineSettings
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Fundamentals.OperationsInfrastructure.Contracts.ActionName = ValidateCommandLineSettings
    Stack:
        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Fundamentals.OperationsInfrastructure.Workflow.Contracts.ComposableActivity.Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        at System.Activities.NativeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
        at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
    Inner exception type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Advisor.Common.Contracts.TargetPlatformNotSupportedException
        Message:
            Invalid target platform specified for assessment. Please choose one of 'SqlServer2012', 'SqlServer2014', 'SqlServer2016', 'SqlServerWindows2017', 'SqlServerLinux2017', 'SqlServerWindows2019', 'SqlServerLinux2019', 'AzureSqlDatabase' or 'ManagedSqlServer'.
        HResult : 0x85FD0003
            FacilityCode : 1533 (5fd)
            ErrorCode : 3 (0003)
```

Comment: Could you please run the command using one of the sql server 2017 options just to see if the error is related to the option 2019?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this. I get the same error no matter what I use for the AssessmentTargetPlatform parameter. I'll keep testing different combinations.

Comment: I dont have any SQL 2017 server. But as stated above I got error no matter what value I put in. Doug I am with you no matter what i put in for 2019 target parameter I get the above error. This tool must not be working I am putting the parameter as it being requested by error message with and without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is misleading. When using an Action of `AssessTargetReadiness`, your choices for `AssessmentTargetPlatform` are limited to:

- ManagedSqlServer (default)
- CosmosDB (private preview)

The [web documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-commandline?view=sql-server-ver15) mentions this, but in a slightly confusing way.

> /AssessmentTargetPlatform Target platform for the assessment:
>
> Supported values for **Assessment**: AzureSqlDatabase, ManagedSqlServer, SqlServer2012, SqlServer2014, SqlServer2016, SqlServerLinux2017 and SqlServerWindows2017 (default) [SqlServerLinux2019 and SqlServerWindows2019 appear to have been added after the documentation was written.]
>
> Supported values for **Target Readiness Assessment**: ManagedSqlServer (default), CosmosDB (preview)

(emphasis mine)

The bare "Assessment" in the first part refers to the other types of assessments, namely `AssessmentEvaluateFeatureParity` and `AssessmentEvaluateCompatibilityIssues`.

BUT, the Target Platform choices are still somewhat more limited than the documentation indicates. The SQLServerWindows2019 option works with the `AssessmentEvaluateCompatibilityIssues` action. But the only ones it seems to allow with the `AssessmentEvaluateFeatureParity` action are AzureSqlDatabase, ManagedSqlServer and SqlServerLinux2017. When I try others, I get this:

> Feature parity rules cannot be run for target platform 'SqlServerWindows2019'. Target platform must be 'AzureSqlDatabase', 'ManagedSqlServer' or 'SqlServerLinux2017' to run feature parity rules.

(SqlServerLinux2019 also works, so it was probably added after the error message was composed.)

So, you'll want to use this command:

```
DmaCmd.exe /AssessmentEvaluateCompatibilityIssues /AssessmentName="MYTESTSERVER" /SourceConnections="Server=MYTESTSERVER;Integrated Security=true" /AssessmentOverwriteResult /AssessmentTargetPlatform="SqlServerWindows2019" /AssessmentResultJson="E:\temp\results\MYTESTSERVER.json"
```

Comment: Thank you Doug the command you have here worked for you? The command you stated here is the command I posted that does not work? You got it to produce results?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. Your command contains "AssessTargetReadiness", while mine contains "AssessmentEvaluateCompatiblityIssues. I think that's the important difference.